# MyFaces CODI and Wildfly not yet usable together?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, myfaces, wildfly

I am currently trying to switch from JBOSS Weld AS7 to Wildfly 8 Beta. I got it compiled but when trying to load the page itself I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: class org.jboss.weld.context.SerializableContextualFactory$PassivationCapableSerializableContextual is no valid conversation scoped bean
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.scope.conversation.ConversationContextAdapter.get(ConversationContextAdapter.java:100) [myfaces-extcdi-bundle-jsf20-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:70) [weld-core-impl-2.1.0.CR1.jar:2013-09-26 16:53]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:81) [weld-core-impl-2.1.0.CR1.jar:2013-09-26 16:53]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:78) [weld-core-impl-2.1.0.CR1.jar:2013-09-26 16:53]
    at myprojectspace.project.OpenScenarioBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getProjectList(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
```

The class, that causes this, i.e. `OpenScenarioBean` is the backing bean for the main page and is declared as follows:

```
@Named
@ViewAccessScoped
public class OpenScenarioBean implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

If I remove the `ViewAccessScoped` and replace it with e.g. `javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped` the web page will display without an exception.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

My guess is: CODI didn't yet do any integration with Wildfly, because during deployment I also receive a couple of warnings like

```
12:26:36,103 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bean] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-001529: An   
InjectionTarget is created for a class   
org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.request.CodiFacesContextFactory which 
does not have any appropriate constructor.
```

But if that's the case, and I want something like `ViewAccessScoped` I guess I should switch to DeltaSpike and hope they're faster in the integration with Wildfly? (But that project is in a really early stage).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure about CODI support, but there should be [MyFaces support](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/StepsToAddMyFacesSupportToWildFly) now. It's part of the [Multi-JSF](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DesignOfWildFlyMulti-JSFFeature) support. It's possible if you install using the install script provided with the MyFaces support and add CODI as a module there it might work. I'm just guess though as I don't know much about CODI.

I did find a [JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-848) about issues with CODI support, but it looks like it's left over from JBoss AS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a Classloading issue with your setup.